# How to I translate this sentence to English?

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

How do I translate this to English?
“사제만 곁에 있으면 불가능한 일 은 아니야.무리하지 말라는 말 잊 지 말라고.”
‘길을 막지 말라고? 보내지 않으면 길을 막는다는 거야 뭐야?’
근무지로 복귀하면서 내내 함 대장 의 말이 걸렸다.

It appears that the sentences don't have anything to do with each other.

Comment: Is there any reason to ask for the translation of a specific sentence in a Korean comic :)?

Answer (score 0):

It is 지천명아비무쌍 1권?

“사제만 곁에 있으면 불가능한 일은 아니야.무리하지 말라는 말 잊지 말라고.”
‘길을 막지 말라고? 보내지 않으면 길을 막는다는 거야 뭐야?’
근무지로 복귀하면서 내내 함 대장 의 말이 걸렸다.

First and second can translated by google translate.
if you cannot translate it, just spacing word.

but Last sentence has google translate some problem.
함 대장 is leader Ham (갑급 무사대장 함대흥, 함대흥 is his full name, 함 is his family name, 대장 means leader), not fleet commander (함대 장, 함대 is fleet, and 장 means leader).

근무지 is workplace or place of duty, but translator said work.
were caught is not good translation. 걸리다 is trouble or be on his mind.

“It’s not impossible as long as the priest is by your side. Don’t forget to say don’t overdo it.”
'Do not block the road? If you don't send it, you're blocking the way, what is it?'
Throughout the return to workplace, the words of leader Ham were caught.